# Virtual Windows 7 on Ubuntu host; Not able to share folders

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, virtualbox, directory

I have a Windows 7 64 bit installed in Virtualbox on my Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit.
I have network running in both, and I would like to share my (Home\Dropbox) folder on my Ubuntu with Windows. But I haven´t been able to find guides on doing this, so can anybody help? I have set the Dropbox folder to share via Virtualbox with Full access and Automount, but I cant find it on the Windows.

Rasmus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you know, I found the answer myself! 
This video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5f1p3fZJPc even do it is made for XP, worked for me.